# How to calculate duration of the animal inside the buffer zone

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, gps, spatial

I have tracking data of birds and I have set a buffer zone. What I am trying to do is to find the duration between the first point inside the buffer zone and the first point outside the buffer zone for each trip of the animal, as a proxy for how much time the animals spent there.

I have identified whether each GPS point is within the buffer zone or not. I made a new data frame which includes all the trips that have at least one GPS point inside the buffer (trips_with_buffer_2016_df). Then I took the first point of each trip that is inside the buffer zone.

```
first_point_in_buffer <- trips_with_buffer_2016_df %>%
  group_by(tripID) %>%
  filter(buffer == "yes") %>%
  slice_min(order_by = DateTime, n = 1)
```

Then created a new column in the data frame which has the DateTime of the the first point of each trip inside the buffer zone and repeats this value for all the GPS points of the same trip.

```
trips_with_buffer_2016_df <- left_join(trips_with_buffer_2016_df, 
                                       first_point_in_buffer %>% select(DateTime, tripID), 
                                       by = "tripID")
```

What I struggle with is to find the first point outside the buffer AFTER the point inside the buffer. The closest I got was this :

```
points_outside_buffer_after <- trips_with_buffer_2016_df %>%
  group_by(tripID) %>%
  filter(buffer == "no" & .$DateTime.x > .$DateTime.y) %>%
  slice_min(order_by = .$DateTime.x, n = 1)
```

where DateTime.x is the DateTime of the GPS in that row, while DateTime.y is the DateTime of the first GPS point in the buffer zone in that row.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Error in `stopifnot()`:
ℹ In argument: `buffer == "no" & .$DateTime.x > .$DateTime.y`.
ℹ In group 1: `tripID = "URI03_104"`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 13 or 1, not size 4483.
```

Apart from this, I noticed that some birds might return in the buffer zone in the same trip. For example a bird might enter and exit and after some time it enters again during the same trip, but my code doesn't capture the second entrance, so I realised I need to change it even more.

Do you have any idea of how can I find the time spent inside inside the buffer zone for each single entrance. I assume something like "for each "yes" in "Buffer" column find the first "no" of the same trip and calculate the difference.

Thanks a lot and apologies for the long post. I'm very new to spatial data.

Comment: Can you share some of your data or make some toy data? You can use `dput` to make something that is easy for others to copy.

Comment: I think that you could facilitate this by turning your point data into a linestring representing the movements, then intersecting that against your zones to get the separate trips in and out of your zones.  YOu can then join or intersect you orignal points to get in/out zone linestring and do some data math on the min and max time and/or duration.  You can do this with the sf package, or leverage some of the packages that are specifically focused on animal movements (ex: "move") they may even have a some canned functions that calculate time in different zones.

Comment: Hello Anders, I eventually solved it but thanks a lot next time i will share data from the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example workflow from using sf as commented above.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)





POINTS <- st_read("your_spatial_data.shp")

#or

POINTS <- st_as_sf("your_xy_dat.csv", coords=c("long_field", "lat_field"))





LINES <- POINTS %>%
  group_by(animal_id) %>%
  arrange(DATE_TIME) %>%
    summarise() %>%
      
    st_cast("LINESTRING")

ZONE <- st_read("your_zones_spatial.shp")





LINE_ZONES <- st_intersection(LINES, ZONE) %>%
  group_by(ZONE_NAME, animal_id) %>%

  summarise(do_union=T) %>%
    
      
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(ID=paste(ZONE_NAME, animal_id, row_number())) 




POINTS_ZONE_ID <- POINTS %>%
  st_join(LINE_ZONES)


POINTS_TIMES <- POINTS_ZONE_ID %>%
  
    st_drop_geometry() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(MIN_TIME=min(DATE_TIME), MAX_TIME=max(DATE_TIME)) %>%
        mutate(DIFF_TIME=MAX_TIME-MIN_TIME )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BEVAN, I tried your code and I really liked the logic, I was able to progress it only up to a point unfortunately. In the end I used dplyr only and the column "buffer:yes/no" since I was sure that the uncertainty I would get in my calculations would be within the 15min gps point interval, since I calculate the interval of gps points in/out of the buffer. I attach the solution here